# How can get value NULL in parse XML iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, null, nsxmlparser

I want to get all value that response from server. I used NSParseXML to parse xml but when element is null, it missed that value and not add to Array.
Example: my xml

```
 <FILE>
     <STATE>2</STATE>
     <MEMO/>
</FILE>
```

In my xml,  is **`Null`**.

This is my code:

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        NSLog(@"Did start element");
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
    {
        XML_FIELD = FILENAME_CLOUD;
        NSLog(@"found rootElement");

        return;
    }
       else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MEMO"])
        {
            NSLog(@"found rootElement");
            XML_FIELD = MEMO;
            return;
        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {


            NSLog(@"Did end element");
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
            {
                NSLog(@"rootelement end");
            }
            XML_FIELD = UNIMPORTANT;

    }
        - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {
       if (XML_FIELD == FILENAME_CLOUD)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
        [FileCompletedArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];

    }
       else if (XML_FIELD == MEMO)
        {
            NSLog(@"Value %@",string);
            [memoarray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
        }

    }
```

When load data into TableView, it not load value null in label. I'm debug, memoarray not add `NULL` value.
How can I get all null value? Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (XML_FIELD == MEMO)` ? doesn't sound valid syntax. by the way, NULL values are empty & nothing, what do you want from it ?

Comment: a null value means that there is nothing there so it probably won't pick it up...

Comment: Is the function being called at all?  If so, it is probably has not "foundCharacters" because there are no characters to find...

Comment: @NGOT: Can you post the full code of XML in this question so that I can help you out?

Comment: I want to get null value because i want show value of MEMO in each row on tableview.If it is NULL, in each row show "Empty". My issue is if it not get null value, in each row not show correctly

Comment: @ParthBhatt: i edited full code parse xml. pls check it. thanks much

Comment: @NGOT By default give all values as NULL. Once you get the XMLParser to work update all the records accordingly. So if no value is found, then by default value will be "NULL" as it won't be found under Parsing and won't be set to any value. Hope this is clear enough. Do let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @NGOT: What is datatype of `XML_FIELD`?

Comment: typedef enum xml_member {
    FILENAME_CLOUD= 1,
    MEMO,
} xml_field;

Comment: xml_field XML_FIELD; XML_FIELD is xml_field enum

Comment: @NGOT OK, try my above comment where I told you to give all element values as NULL initially. Also can you post the response of XMLParser which you find in console?

Comment: MemoArray is show 6 objects, but my data is 20 objects. each objects if Memo is null, it now add to Memoarray. So when I load data on tableview, it not correct.

Comment: My console print:cldst[3377:c07] Memo string (
    "hello world",
    "hello world\n",
    "hello world",
    "hello world\n",
    "hello world",
    "hello world\n"
)

Comment: @NGOT: Can you not try something like this before parsing:          [MemoArray removeAllObjects];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
 [MemoArray addObject:NULL];
}

Comment: NO, i dont use your code in my app

Comment: @NGOT: Ok final question. Does `didEndElement` gets called for Element "MEMO"?

Comment: NO, in didEndElement not call for Element "MEMO

Comment: in didEndElement, only call Element"FILENAME" if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FILENAME"])
        {
            NSLog(@"rootelement end");
        }